# Why am I getting a 404 when accessing Odoo over XML-RPC?

Tags: xml-rpc, odoo-9

I'm attempting to connect to Odoo 9 using XML-RPC. I've tried the url with xmlrpc/2/common, xmlrpc/common, and various other combinations. I'm only trying to get the version by passing version(), so authentication is not the issue. I'm using Nginx as reverse proxy and I've tried disabling Nginx and connecting directly to Odoo using various ports including the ones in the config. XML-RPC is enabled in my config file.

Haven't been able to post to the Odoo forums, and haven't had an answer from the IRC channel. I've now spent two days on this and could really use some help.

Can anyone confirm that xmlrpc/2/common is the correct path on Odoo 9?

Is there an Odoo instance somewhere that is known to work that I can try connecting to?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a networking issue. To troubleshoot the issue you should really have access to ideally your firewall, webserver logs (in your case nginx), and odoo logs. I will assume you have at least your webserver logs and odoo logs. Check your config and startup script to determine what port you are running xmlrpc on.

When you execute your xmlrpc commands view the incoming requests on odoo (ensure you have logging set to info or even better debug_rpc_answer). For docs on logging check out [this](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/cmdline.html).  You should at least see the request successful or not on your logs. If you do not see the request at all then nginx is not forwarding properly (or firewall is blocking).

You really want to verify at every point that your request is getting through and then on the other end the response is coming back. Your firewall can let requests in but block outgoing if configured to do so.

```
import xmlrpclib
url = "localhost:8069"
common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
common.version()
```

If you cant run this on the host running your odoo server something is off. Check the port or if xmlrpc = True is enabled in your config. From there you can execute from another computer and then introduce your webserver.

Comment: And what is the url for my online odoo version ?
lets say for eg.,my databse = 'my_odoo_db', and uname = 'uname_odoo', and pass = 'pass-odoo'

Comment: When you log into your online odoo system. The url in your browser would be the url. In that case it may be that apache/ nginx is forwarding port 80 to port 8069

Comment: Thaks Phillip i know that, but for eg. my currently live url is "https://air-flow-master-staging-88906.dev.odoo.com/web#home" then how to pass with port

Secondly, 8069 is a local port for default,but  where to find port for live?

Comment: The thing is, I do not think you have to worry about passing the port. Apache and nginx are likely doing that for you. However it would not hurt to try https://air-flow-master-staging-88906.dev.odoo.com:8069/web#home%22

Comment: The thing is. When acting behind a proxy it is common to block access to port 8069 and so you may not get through with your request.

Comment: I just checked your endpoint. Port 8069 is not being forwarded.

Answer (score 1):

Odoo version 10:

Check your Odoo config file or command line

```
xmlrpc_interface = 0.0.0.0
xmlrpc = True
xmlrpc-port = 8069
```

Run this python code:

```
import xmlrpclib
common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/2/common')
print common.version()
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this problem is that you need to make sure that the url only accesses one database.
Because the database cannot be specified when common.version() is called.
To do this, you can use the

1. You do have only one database.
   or 2. with dbfilter configuration.